# How do I override padding-left that has !important attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a below code and I want to override padding-left element that has `!important` attribute. Can anyone provide me any idea ?

```
jQuery("a.orderLink").css("padding-left", "300px", "important");
```

Comment: you really want to use jquery ? can you provide the html and css of the specific element ?

Comment: did you try `jQuery("a.orderLink").css("padding-left", "300px !important"); `

Comment: You probably want to go and fix the reason it's been given `!important` in the first place.  You'll just end up in an arms race otherwise - you really need to use that sparingly.  If you need to override it, it can't be that `!important`.

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen your code might not work. Some browsers have a bug with this syntax and it won't be fixed. Have a look [here](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11173).

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen... I have tried but it is not working...

Comment: @MihaiT... Here is the CSS... a.orderLink:link,
a.orderLink:visited {

  font-weight: bold;
  color: #028940;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url("/~/media/C41A83E95BE94F6E873ED29BB40B90A7.png") left no-repeat;
  padding-left: 28px !important;
  margin: 0;
}

Comment: we are getting there. and the html ?

Comment: @MihaiT... You can go to http://www.subway.com/en-us website, there is Order online CTA on top of right...Currently we are using the below javascript code...     function myFunction() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("a.orderLink.csshidepipe");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].style.color = "#FFC214";
   x[i].style.backgroundImage = "none";
   x[i].innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-shopping-cart hidden-xs disabled fa-lg'></i>  Order Online";
  };
jQuery("a.orderLink").css("padding-left", "300px", "important"); 
// Above is my latest attempt;
};
myFunction();

Comment: see my answer below for the solution ;)

Comment: @MihaiT... Thank you so much... It some how works for me... I want to bold that particular order online text but "font-weight: bold" is not working. Is there something else we can do ?

Comment: please comment at my answer. not here. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a workaround for this using cssText. so adding to the whole CSS of the link the part you want with important ;

> The cssText property sets or returns the contents of a style declaration as a string.

see below :

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("a.orderLink.csshidepipe");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.color = "#FFC214";
    x[i].style.backgroundImage = "none";
    x[i].innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-shopping-cart hidden-xs disabled fa-lg'></i> Order Online";
  };
  $("a.orderLink").css("cssText","padding-left:250px!important");
 
};
myFunction();
```

```css
a.orderLink
{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #028940;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url("/~/media/C41A83E95BE94F6E873ED29BB40B90A7.png") left no-repeat;
  padding-left: 28px !important;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="orderLink">I have padding</a>
```

option2 giving a class to the link and give it the important style

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("a.orderLink.csshidepipe");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.color = "#FFC214";
    x[i].style.backgroundImage = "none";
    x[i].innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-shopping-cart hidden-xs disabled fa-lg'></i> Order Online";
  };
  $("a.orderLink").addClass("withPadding");
 
};
myFunction();
```

```css
a.orderLink
{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #028940;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url("/~/media/C41A83E95BE94F6E873ED29BB40B90A7.png") left no-repeat;
  padding-left: 28px !important;
  margin: 0;
}
a.orderLink.withPadding {
padding-left:250px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="orderLink">I have padding</a>
```

this is solving your issue but not the core problem. the core problem is using `!important` in the first place. i strongly suggest AGAINST using it . It creates a [Snowball effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_effect) that will affect your whole coding . so try not using it in CSS or anywhere else unless it is the only way and even then, reconsider :)

Comment: @Ishan to get the font bold, try adding or removing `:link` from `a.orderLink` -> `a.orderLink:link`

Comment: @Ishan i added another solution. adding a class. check if that works for you better

Answer (score 1):

You can define a class/selector where you can override the same property. Make sure this definition appears after `.orderLink`

#### Class

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", handleClick);

function handleClick(){
  document.querySelector('.test').classList.add("override")
}
```

```css
.test{
  padding-left: 10px!important;
}

.override{
  padding-left: 100px!important;
}
```

```html
<a class="test" href="#"> Test </a>
<button id="btn">Override</button>
```

#### Selector

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", handleClick);

function handleClick(){
  document.querySelector('.test').classList.add("override")
}
```

```css
a.test.override{
  padding-left: 100px!important;
}

.test{
  padding-left: 10px!important;
}
```

```html
<a class="test" href="#"> Test </a>
<button id="btn">Override</button>
```

**Note:** its better to use CSS specificities instead of `!important`. Sample:

```css
.test {
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

p.test{
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}

p .test{
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

div .test{
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}

div span .test{
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a class="test" href="#"> Test </a>
<p class="test" href="#"> Test </p>
<p><a class="test" href="#"> Test </a></p>
<div><a class="test" href="#"> Test </a></div> <br/>

<div><span><a class="test" href="#"> Test </a><span></div>
```

#### Reference:

- [Specifics on CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 0):

body a.orderLink { padding-left: 301px !important}